# New class to use other class attributes

Tags: css

I am wondering if it is possible to use @extend to utilize properties of one class in another. For example, if I have two CSS files that load on the same page in the following order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/one.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/two.css" media="screen">
```

where **one.css** has class:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

Can I do something like that in **two.css**:

```
.bar {
  @extend .foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll require a pre- or post-processor to achieve such things, or a CSS-in-JS solution.

You could consider:

1. a BEM-like approach to cascade what's common and override what's unique.

```css
.foo {
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}

.baz {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo">This is FOO</span>
<span class="foo bar">This is FOO + BAR</span>
<span class="foo baz">This is FOO + BAZ</span>
```

... or

2. a CSS Custom Properties (a.k.a CSS Variables) to apply and override more flexibly.

```css
:root {
  --main-color: black;
}

.foo {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.bar {
  --main-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo">This is FOO</span>
<span class="foo bar">This is FOO + BAR</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now pure CSS don't have any mechanism like this, I know there is a way in Sass to do this with @extend. For some cases it's enough to use comma separated selectors for example:

```
.foo,.bar{
  font-size:40px;
}
.bar{
  color:red;
}
```

in this example You are doing common part for .foo and .bar selectors and add color:red only for .bar